# How to copy material to another object but not link it?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

[image]I'm trying to copy the matrial from one object to another by using CTRL + L and using link material. But I want it to be its own material because when I make changes on one of them the other gets affected. The videos I've seen just say "materals" but when I press CTRL+L I get link materials.

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is really not that hard that you need different shortcut or something. Just use Link material and after that press this small button here and it will create it's own material for second object:
[image]

After that the object 1 will have material.002 and second object will have material.003 that is same but individual on it's own

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when using node groups: node groups are datablocks that can be used by many materials, if this is the case changing a value into a node group will be reflected in all materials which share the use of the same nodegroup.

To solve you have many ways, two of them:

1. expose into the input of the node group the values you want to change, so that every nodegroup will have it's own values.
2. click on the number of nodegroup users, to create a single user copy of the nodegtoup you need to edit.

[image]